# extract information from java class

Tags: java, import

I have a java class called httpdstatistics.java that belongs to a web server (Jigsaw) that generates statistics about this server(hits,thread,ecc.). I would export this information to an other class created by me. Which could be the best way to do what I'm asking to?is it enough to import this class httpdstatistics.java in my project  and after calling get method to obtain data?

```
// httpdStatistics.java
// $Id: httpdStatistics.java,v 1.10 2003/02/25 17:51:43 ylafon Exp $
// (c) COPYRIGHT MIT and INRIA, 1996.
// Please first read the full copyright statement in file COPYRIGHT.html

package org.w3c.jigsaw.http;

import java.net.URL;

// FIXME

import org.w3c.jigsaw.http.socket.SocketClientFactory;
import org.w3c.jigsaw.http.socket.SocketClientFactoryStats;

/**
 * This class maintains server wide statistics about hits.
 * This class should probably be coded as a resource itself, and made 
 * accessible through a specific HTTPResource. I am just having fun 
 * for the time being.
 */

public class httpdStatistics {
    protected httpd server = null ;

    /**
     * The min processing time in ms.
     */
    protected long r_min = Long.MAX_VALUE ;
    /**
     * The min processing time in ms for dynamic content
     */
    protected long rd_min = Long.MAX_VALUE ;
    /**
     * The URL that has been processed the fastest.
     */
    protected URL u_min = null ;
    /**
     * The URL that has been processed the fastest for dynamic content
     */
    protected URL ud_min = null ;
    /**
     * The maximum processing time in ms.
     */
    protected long r_max = 0 ;
    /**
     * The maximum processing time in ms for dynamic content
     */
    protected long rd_max = 0 ;
    /**
     * The URL that has been processed the slowest.
     */
    protected URL u_max = null ;
    /**
     * The URL that has been processed the slowest for dynamic content
     */
    protected URL ud_max = null ;
    /**
     * The total number of hits.
     */
    protected long t_hits  = 0 ;
    /**
     * The total number of hits for dynamic content
     */
    protected long td_hits  = 0 ;   
    /**
     * The total number of emited bytes.
     */
    protected long t_bytes = 0 ;
    /**
     * The total number of emited bytes for dynamic content
     */
    protected long td_bytes = 0 ;
    /**
     * The total time spent in processing requests in ms.
     */
    protected long t_req = 0 ;
    /**
     * The total time spent in processing requests in ms for dynamic content
     */
    protected long td_req = 0 ;
    /**
     * The date at which the server was started (ms since Java epoch).
     */
    protected long start_time = 0;

    // FIXME temporary hack
    protected SocketClientFactoryStats factoryStats = null;
    protected boolean init = false;

    /**
     * Update the current statistics with the given request.
     * @param client The client that processed the request.
     * @param request The request that has been processed.
     * @param nbytes The number of emited bytes in reply's body.
     * @param duration The processing time of the request.
     */

    protected synchronized void updateStatistics(Client client
                         , Request request, Reply reply
                         , int nbytes
                         , long duration) {
    if (reply.isDynamic()) {
        if ( duration > rd_max ) {
        rd_max = duration ;
        ud_max = request.getURL() ;
        }
        if ( duration < rd_min ) {
        rd_min = duration ;
        ud_min = request.getURL() ;
        }
        td_req   += duration ;
        td_bytes += nbytes ;
        td_hits++ ;
    } else {
        if ( duration > r_max ) {
        r_max = duration ;
        u_max = request.getURL() ;
        }
        if ( duration < r_min ) {
        r_min = duration ;
        u_min = request.getURL() ;
        }
        t_req   += duration ;
        t_bytes += nbytes ;
        t_hits++ ;
    }
    }

    /**
     * Get the current server load.
     * @return A number between <strong>1</strong> and <strong>4</strong>.
     */

    public int getServerLoad() {
    if (!init) {
        initFactoryStats();
    }
    if (factoryStats != null) {
        return factoryStats.getLoadAverage();
    }
    // return server.pool.loadavg;
    return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Get the number of free threads in the server.
     * @return The number of threads ready to server client requests.
     */

    public int getFreeThreadCount() {
    if (!init) {
        initFactoryStats();
    }
    if (factoryStats != null) {
        return factoryStats.getFreeConnectionsCount();
    }
        // return server.pool.freeCount;
    return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Get the number of idle threads in the server.
     * Idle threads are the threads ready to accept more requests on a given
     * connection.
     * @return The number of idle threads.
     */

    public int getIdleThreadCount() {
    if (!init) {
        initFactoryStats();
    }
    if (factoryStats != null) {
        return factoryStats.getIdleConnectionsCount();
    }
    // return server.pool.idleCount;
    return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Get the total number of client threads.
     * @return The total number of created threads.
     */

    public int getTotalThreadCount() {
    if (!init) {
        initFactoryStats();
    }
    if (factoryStats != null) {
        return factoryStats.getClientCount();
    }
    // return server.pool.clientCount;
    return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Get the total number of hits.
     * @return The total number of processed requests since the server is up.
     */

    public long getHitCount() {
    return (t_hits+td_hits) ;
    }

    /**
     * Get the total number of hits for dynamic content.
     * @return The total number of processed requests since the server is up.
     */

    public long getDynamicHitCount() {
    return td_hits ;
    }

    /**
     * Get the total number of hits for static content.
     * @return The total number of processed requests since the server is up.
     */

    public long getStaticHitCount() {
    return t_hits ;
    }

    /**
     * Get the mean request processing time.
     * @return The average time to process a request.
     */

    public long getMeanRequestTime() {
    return ((t_hits+td_hits) > 0) ? (t_req+td_req) / (t_hits+td_hits) : -1;
    }

    /**
     * Get the mean request processing time for dynamic content
     * @return The average time to process a request.
     */

    public long getMeanDynamicRequestTime() {
    return (td_hits > 0) ? (td_req / td_hits) : -1;
    }

    /**
     * Get the mean request processing time.
     * @return The average time to process a request.
     */

    public long getMeanStaticRequestTime() {
    return (t_hits > 0) ? (t_req / t_hits) : -1;
    }

    /**
     * Get the max request processing time.
     * @return A long giving the maximum duration for a request.
     */

    public long getMaxRequestTime() {
    return Math.max(r_max,rd_max) ;
    }

    /**
     * Get the max request processing time for dynamic content
     * @return A long giving the maximum duration for a request.
     */

    public long getMaxDynamicRequestTime() {
    return rd_max ;
    }
    /**
     * Get the max request processing time for static content
     * @return A long giving the maximum duration for a request.
     */

    public long getMaxStaticRequestTime() {
    return r_max ;
    }

    /**
     * Get the URL of the request that took the longest time to be processed.
     * @return A String giving the URL of the corresponding request, or
     *    <strong>null</strong> if no request has been processed yet.
     */

    public URL getMaxRequestURL() {
    return (r_max > rd_max) ? u_max : ud_max ;
    }

    /**
     * Get the min request processing time.
     * @return A long giving the minimum request processing time.
     */

    public long getMinRequestTime() {
    return Math.min(r_min, rd_min) ;
    }

    /**
     * Get the min request processing time for dynamic content
     * @return A long giving the minimum request processing time.
     */

    public long getMinDynamicRequestTime() {
    return rd_min ;
    }

    /**
     * Get the min request processing time.
     * @return A long giving the minimum request processing time.
     */

    public long getMinStaticRequestTime() {
    return r_min ;
    }
    /**
     * Get the URL of the request that took the smallest time to be processed.
     * @return A String giving the URL of the corresponding request, or
     *    <strong>null</strong> if no request has been processed yet.
     */

    public URL getMinRequestURL() {
    return (r_min < rd_min) ? u_min : ud_min ;
    }

    /**
     * Get the total number of bytes emited.
     * @return A long giving the total number of bytes emited by the server.
     *    This count that not include the reply's header, but only the reply's
     *    body (or <em>entity</em> size).
     */

    public long getEmittedBytes() {
    return t_bytes + td_bytes ;
    }

    /**
     * Get the time at which the server was started.
     * @return A number of milliseconds since java epoch, giving the date
     * at which the server started.
     */

    public long getStartTime() {
    return start_time;
    }

    /**
     * As we can't start the after the server socket (client factory)
     * we have to create when requested, which is always after the creation
     * of the whole server..
     */
    private void initFactoryStats() {
    if (server.factory instanceof SocketClientFactory) {
        SocketClientFactory f = (SocketClientFactory) server.factory;
        factoryStats = new SocketClientFactoryStats(f);
    }
    init = true;
    }

    httpdStatistics (httpd server) {
    this.server     = server ;
    this.start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is NOT quite clear in its current form?

Comment: You need to import all the dependencies in your project also like SocketClientFactory